# How can I resolve references to bibliography entries in a jupyter notebook using pandoc & --citeproc

Tags: jupyter, pandoc

I have a bibliography file with many citations, and a variety of jupyter notebooks which refer to these. Previously these were processed using jupyter book, but I now need to create raw notebook versions.

With that in mind I tried this

Create a simple bibliography **bib.bib**

```
@article{smid_development_2021,
     title = {Development of the {Advanced} {Encryption} {Standard}},
     volume = {126},
     url = {https://www.nist.gov/publications/development-advanced-encryption-standard},
     abstract = {Strong cryptographic algorithms are essential for the protection of stored and transmitted data throughout the world.},
     language = {en},
     urldate = {2023-05-17},
     journal = {NIST},
     author = {Smid, Miles E. and Foti, James},
     month = aug,
     year = {2021},
     note = {Last Modified: 2021-10-14T05:10-04:00
 Publisher: Miles E. Smid, James Foti},
     file = {Full Text PDF:/Users/dasc/Zotero/storage/5YCK8JKG/Smid and Foti - 2021 - Development of the Advanced Encryption Standard.pdf:application/pdf},
}
```

Now create a simple notebook in **lesson1.ipynb** with a single reference of the form *AES[@smid_development_2021]* or in full:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "id": "364e8ef9-eebe-4da8-b3e2-0005c94392ae",
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "# Test document for pandoc\n",
    "\n",
    "We have just one article on the development of AES[@smid_development_2021]\n",
    "\n",
    "# References\n",
    "\n"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.11.4"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 5
}
```

I also want these citations in IEEE format, so download

**https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/ieee.csl** as **ieee.csl**

I then invoke

```
pandoc -f ipynb -t ipynb --citeproc lesson1.ipynb -o lesson1-withrefs.ipynb --bibliography bib.bib --csl ieee.csl
```

But the output virtually identical to input, other than minor metadata differences

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {},
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "# Test document for pandoc\n",
    "\n",
    "We have just one article on the development of AES[@smid_development_2021]\n",
    "\n",
    "# References\n",
    "\n"
   ],
   "id": "364e8ef9-eebe-4da8-b3e2-0005c94392ae"
  }
 ],
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 5,
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "name": "python3",
   "display_name": "Python 3 (ipykernel)",
   "language": "python"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "name": "python",
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": "3"
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.11.4"
  }
 }
}
```

I then tried other variations such as writing to html, or markdown (gfm), but wasn't able to get the references expanded.

I WAS able to process the bibliography references completely in another test using a markdown input file of

```
---
# Reference
bibliography: references.bib
link-citations: true
csl: ieee.csl
nocite: "@*"
---
```

and appropriate invocation changes

So I presume I've made a really simple/silly mistake, but I've yet to figure out where. pandoc is new to me, and I'm also unfamilar with it's capabilities writing .ipynb

Can anyone spot the obvious error?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Pandoc's Jupyter Notebook writer supports what you want. Taking for example the Markdown to Markdown, if the input is

```
We have just one article on the development of AES[@smid_development_2021]
```

the output of `pandoc -f markdown -t markdown --citeproc --bibliography bib.bib mwe.md` is

```
We have just one article on the development of
AES[@smid_development_2021]
```

My understanding is that Pandoc mostly convert bibliograph to HTML and LaTeX.